# ArrayList Method: iterator()

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I cannot find out what this method does. Can someone please explain?

Example:

```
for (Iterator ite = list.iterator(); ite.hasNext(); )
```

Thanks, I just started learning java. Currently grade 9.

Comment: I don't want to vote you down, but google the method and read the javadoc. Saying thanks and giving useless information is considered noise because it doesn't help you or us.

Comment: it's a `for` loop like `for(initialization; termination;increment)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just "reading" the list with an iterator (useful if you want to remove elements from the list while reading).

You can get an element from the iterator with

```
Item item = ite.next();
```

if you want to remove the item from the list you can do simply

```
ite.remove();
```

You can loop a list also with simpler for, like

```
for (Item item : list) {
    System.out.println(item.toString());
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    Item item = list.get(i);
    System.out.println(item.toString());
}
```

but with these, if you try to do `list.remove(item)` or `list.remove(i)` you will raise an exception (ConcurrentModificationException if I'm not wrong).

Answer (score 0):

At a very basic level, an iterator "walks through" the list until it gets to the end.  So in that method, you're creating an object that points at one object in the list.  When you call `next()` on the iterator, it moves to the next object in the list.  And when you call `hasNext()` on the iterator, you're asking whether the iterator has anywhere else to go, or whether it's at the end of the list.  `hasNext()` will return true if the iterator has a `next()` and false otherwise.

You likely want to create your for loop like this:

```
for ( Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next() )
```

which creates a new iterator for the list (the first element).  Each time the loop comes back, it calls `iter.next()` which makes the iterator point to the next element in the list.  When you've gotten to the end of the list, `iter.hasNext()` is no longer true, and so the loop breaks.

In short, you're just creating a for loop that goes through every element of the list.